# Finding the number of independent subsets vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

This is a try question from a textbook which interest me. Assume $X(G)$ is the number of subsets of vertices that are independent. E.g. $X(P^2) = 5$ (the empty set, 3 singletons, and the pair of leaves). Then find the following:

(a) $X(K^{2022})$ where $K$ is a complete graph.

(b) $X(K_{2022, 2022})$ where $K$ is a complete graph.

(c) $X(P^{2022})$ where $P$ is a path.

Pardon my ignorance but here is what I know so far:

For (a) and (b) since the graph is a complete graph means all vertices are connected such that there are no independent vertices, so my first thought is that the answer could be an empty set but I am not sure about that. For (c), it's confusing.

Comment: I think the notations are:  $X(K^{2022})$ means find the number of subsets of independent vertices of a complete graph (=pairwise non-adjacent vertices of a complete graph); $X(K_{2022, 2022})$ means find the number of subsets of independent vertices of a complete 2022-partite graph (=every partition class contains exactly 2022 vertices);  $X(P^{2022})$ means find the number of subsets of independent vertices of length 2022. (=number of edges of the path). Different texts use different notations but the same implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is $2023$ (only empty set and one-element set), (b) is $2^{2023}-1$ (each part $2^{2022}$, and minus the emptyset that counted twice), they are trivial, and we leave it as exercise (lol)

For (c), consider the recurrence: suppose we have $P^n$, and we have $A_1A_2\dots A_{n+1}$ where there is a edge for $A_iA_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. Consider two case:

If we choose $A_{n+1}$, we will not choose $A_{n}$, so an independent set include $A_{n+1}$ if and only if it deleted $A_{n+1}$ is an independent subset of $\{A_1,\dots,A_{n-1}\}$, therefore in this case we have $X(P_{n-2})$.

If we don't choose $A_{n+1}$, an independent set does not include $A_{n+1}$ if and only if itis an independent subset of $\{A_1,\dots,A_{n}\}$, therefore in this case we have $X(P_{n-1})$.

So we have $X(P^n)=X(P^{n-1})+X(P^{n-2})$.

Notice that $X(P_0)=2$ and $X(P_1)=3$, we have $X(P^{2022})$ is $F_{2025}$ where $F$ is the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @bof oh, I missed that, I will add it on.

Comment: @bof I know that, that's why the vertices are $A_1,A_2,\dots , A_{n+1}$ and the answer is $F_{2025}$ instead of $F_{2024}$

Comment: @holala It means that the answer is $2^{2023}-1$. This is because you may count $2^{2022}$ sets in each part (so in total $2^{2023}$), but minus one because you double counted the empty set.

Comment: @holala Sorry, I don't.